# "NUL" character is missing

Tags: c#, notepad++

I have got characters on notepad++ like below screenshot.

[image]

When I am copied and pasted same line in other new notepad++ file, "NUL" character was missing. Actually "NUL" character replaced by space(" ").

[image]

I want original line as it is. What I can do to get same line ?

Please help me to get the solution.

**Why it is required:** I am doing one project in C#. In that I am reading the content of file in a string format and creating new file with the same content. So after creation of new file, I notice same behavior that "NUL" character was missing. This problem is creating hinder in my project.

Comment: Forget notepad++, it's a distraction. C# does not copy bytes by sending them through the clipboard. Show us the c# code that needs fixing

Comment: Notepad is for text only, its not for editing bytes, some bytes cant be displayed as text that's why they don't get copied.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

normally you dont copy/paste binary data like that.
notepad++ offers you instead a function for handling that kind of data..

you find that under "edit"->"paste special"-> and there you can "copy bin content"
and of course somewhere later "paste bin content"

[image]